# Does any of those internet tips to recondition Li-ion batteries actually work?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

If you google "fix liion battery" of similar, you'll get the following tips on various sites:

- **Fully discharge and charge battery** - this sounds like completely bad advice since discharging Li-ion batteries under 1V permanently damages them
- **Freeze the battery for 24 or more hours** - I think freezing the battery increases risk of rupture due to thermal contraction/expansion
- **Shock the battery with 5V** - this advice is based on some Li-ion battery sleep mode, I don't really understand what it's about
- **Connect the battery anti-parallel to another working battery** - I don't see how this is different from using charger, but if it doesn't work it will multiply the amount of broken batteries.

So is any of those common tips viable, or are they just dangerous experiments that yield nothing?

Comment: Yeah, some of these, especially the anti parallel one seem fishy.

Comment: If you want to risk self shorting any one of these methods can disturb dendrites enough to fizzle them out or short the cell. But if electrode diffused into electrolyte from under voltage or extreme heat would degrade ion transfer efficacy...  be very cautious with these experiments with a fire/flame retardant with any signs of toxic gassing. LiPo cells are not exactly like Panasonic Self-healing plastic caps where you can burn out a micro-particle impurity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Fully discharge and charge battery

This can sometimes be useful as a step to correct capacity estimates in some "smart" battery packs, like those found in a cell phone or laptop. It is unhelpful for batteries which do not have a built-in controller, and outright dangerous for unprotected cells.

> Freeze the battery for 24 or more hours

Chilling can be helpful for some other electronic devices, like mechanical hard disks. However, I see no reason it would be helpful for a battery. Discharging a lithium-ion battery below its minimum operating temperature (~5°C) greatly reduces its effective capacity on that charge cycle, and charging it at low temperatures can cause permanent damage.

> Shock the battery with 5V

Protected cells will often cut off entirely (terminals permanently read 0V) after being discharged below their absolute minimum voltage (~2.5V). Applying 5V externally might be a way to force the cell to start charging again. However, any cell that's been discharged to this point has already been damaged -- this procedure just resets the protection circuit to allow it to be used again. Additionally, this technique should *never* be applied to a battery which does not have a protection circuit, or which is not in undervoltage cutoff.

> Connect the battery anti-parallel to another working battery

Applying a reverse voltage to a battery -- especially a lithium-ion battery -- is a terrible idea, and is likely to cause the battery to fail violently. Do not do this under any circumstances.